# Get wordpress post in diffrent div but one by one

Tags: wordpress

I have 10 post in my wordpress blog and i want to something like that:
div class="something1"
post1
post5
post9
/div

div class="something2"
post2
post6
post10
/div
div class="something3"
post3
post7


post4
post8
/div

I have no idea, but i must need it, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop you need to increment your div with php. I haven't tested this, but this should work:

```
<div class="yourClass">
<?php
    $myCustomClass = 0;
    $args = array
    (
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'orderby'     => 'name',
        'order'       => 'DEC',
        'post_type'   => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
        <?php $myCustomClass++ ?>

            <div class="myCustomClass-<?php echo $myCustomClass;?>">

                <h2>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                    </a>
                </h2>

                <div class="my-post-content">

                    <?php the_content(); ?>

                </div>

            </div>
<? endwhile; ?>
</div>
```